# WP-API and HTML tags

Tags: html, angularjs, wordpress, wp-api

I'm pulling data from an external site using WP-API and displaying it using AngularJS - http://dev.5874.co.uk/goshooting/search-the-shooting-club-directory/

The data is pulling in fine but it's showing the HTML tags such as

how can I stop this? I'm using Advanced custom fields too which may be contributing.

```
<div  ng-controller="northWestCtrl">
              <div ng-repeat="d in data">
                <h2 class="entry-title title-post">{{d.title}}</h2>
                <img src="{{d.acf.logo}}">
                <div id="listing-contact">Contact: {{d.acf.contact}}, {{d.acf.position}}</div>
                <div id="listing-address-1">
                  {{d.acf.address_1}}, {{d.acf.address_2}} {{d.acf.address_3}} {{d.acf.town}} {{d.acf.county}} {{d.acf.postcode}}
                </div>
                <div id="listing-phone">Telephone: {{d.acf.telephone}}</div>
                <div id="listing-mobile">Mobile: {{d.acf.mobile}}</div>
                <div id="listing-email">Email: {{d.acf.email}}</div>
                <div id="listing-website">Website: <a href="{{d.acf.website}}">{{d.acf.website}}</a></div>
                <div id="listing-established">Established: {{d.acf.established}}</div>
                <div id="listing-about">About: {{d.acf.about}}</div>
                <div id="listing-mailingaddress">Mailing Address: {{d.acf.mailing_address_}}, {{d.acf.mailing_address_2}}, {{d.acf.mailing_address_3}}, {{d.acf.mailing_town}}, {{d.acf.mailing_county}}, {{d.acf.mailing_postcode}}</div>
                <div id="listing-directions">Directions: {{d.acf.directions}}</div>
                <div id="scd-link"><a href="{{d.link}}">View on The Shooting Club Directory</a></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Here is a working code pen also - `http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yePYdq`

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you right you Use this site for getting your data http://scd.blaze.wpengine.com/wp-json/posts?type=listings&filter[listing_area]=northeast with API

Also your console display an error

```
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://scd.blaze.wpengine.com/wp-json/posts?type=listings&filter[listing_area]=northeast. Origin http://dev.5874.co.uk is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Maybe this link will be helpful [Origin is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

Comment: Yes I get the data from the API URL, but it's pulling in the HTML tags which I need to get rid of and just show the text without tags like <p></p>

Comment: Also I think the error is to do with my development site, this code will be gong into a different site which should be fine @Dreamm